# js php, ajax remembers previously loaded content

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have the weird issue, I have been looking for the solution for a while with no result. I'm developing a website, decided to load every subpage(content) dynamically via AJAX(also .js and .css files for each subpage). Now, when I'm working on it and change scripts/css for some file and refresh the page, it doesn't load them. It's like AJAX remembers the previous version, because when I turn it all of and come back after few hours it changes (!). Any ideas for this one? I want to avoid remembering anything by site memory(or anything) so I could work on this normally. I don't use jquery, I use pure js and my own function for ajax connection, maybe I should add there something? Here it is:

```
function sendQuery( data )
{
    var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = data["url"];
    var params = "";
    var query = data["params"];
    for(var key in query)
    params+=key+"="+query[key]+"&";
    params=params.substring(0,params.length-1);
    http.open("POST", url, true);
    http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    http.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
    http.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
    http.send(params);
    http.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
        if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200)
        {
            data["result"](http.responseText);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is exactly, but you will have a hard time opening a specific page directly using `POST` instead of `GET`. You should use `GET` and change the url / path so that you can load and bookmark individual pages.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure entirely what you mean, but this sounds like a caching issue, why not append the current time or a similar random string to the request as a separate parameter? This level of uniqueness should prevent the request response from being cached by the browser.

e.g. `'?nocache='+new Date().getTime()`

You may also want to prevent the server side response from caching the content returned by the call by setting the appropriate headers (e.g.):

```
response.setHeader( "Pragma", "no-cache" );
response.setHeader( "Cache-Control", "no-cache" );
response.setDateHeader( "Expires", 0 );
```

Comment: how exactly do I set headers for response?

Answer (score 0):

It seems highly related with your caching policy.

If you're hosting site with apache,

Check .htaccess in your root directory you might see something like this:

```
# Set up 2 Hour caching on commonly updated files
<FilesMatch "\.(xml|txt|html|js|css)$">
ExpiresDefault A7200
Header append Cache-Control "proxy-revalidate"
</FilesMatch>
```

The setting above set expire time to 7200 seconds = 2 hours.

To disable cache under development:

```
# Force no caching for dynamic files
<FilesMatch "\.(xml|txt|html|js|css)$">
ExpiresActive Off
Header set Cache-Control "private, no-cache, no-store, proxy-revalidate, no-transform"
Header set Pragma "no-cache"
</FilesMatch>
```

Then it should works properly.

Another way is to change this line:

```
var url = data["url"];
```

To:

```
var url = data["url"]+"&ts="+(new Date().valueOf());
```

To avoid the cache. Note: it's just pseudo code. "?" Should be handled if there hasn't one.

Hope it helps :)